# Possible to declare/assign an int* in one line?

Tags: c, pointers

Is it possible to do the following in C?

```
int *NumPtr = & (int) 44;
```

Or does this need to be done 'through' an intermediary variable, such as:

```
int Num = 3, *NumPtr;
NumPtr = &Num;
```

Comment: What do you expect `int *NumPtr = & (int) 44;` to do? What is it taking an address of? What happens when you try it? I suggest compiling and running to find out.

Comment: `44` is a literal - that is to say, it is not allocated memory in the same way as a variable is. So, getting address for it, is not exactly feasible!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
int *NumPtr = &(int){44};
```

Compound literals are usually used to create anonymous arrays or structs, but they can be used as here as well.

Comment: that is cool, thank you!     `NumPtr = & (int) {44};` `printf("Num: %d, NumPtr: %d (%p)\n", Num, *NumPtr, NumPtr);`